# Smarter ways to write APEX class which consists of multiple methods executing a DML statement

Tags: apex, query, cpulimit

I have a scheduled job that executes several methods from one apex class, code as follow;

```
public class dailyUpdates{

    Date Dday = system.today();

    public void scheduledUpdates(){
        system.debug('******start*******');
        activeContractStage();
        ExpiredCLIStatus();
        SalesStageRenewal();
        SalesStageExpired();
        SalesStageLost();
        SalesStageLostWinBack();
        SalesStageColdMakeHot();
        SalesStagePendingConversion();
        SalesStageExpiredFreeTrial();


    }

    public void activeContractStage(){

        // The query here

        update liCon;
    }

    public void ExpiredCLIStatus(){
        // The query here

        update licli;
    }

    public void SalesStageExpired(){
        // The query here

        update liacc;

    }

    public void SalesStageRenewal(){

        // The query here

        update liacc;
    }

    public void SalesStageLost(){
        // The query here

        update liacc;
    }

    public void SalesStagePendingConversion(){

        // The query here

        update liacc;

    }
    public void SalesStageExpiredFreeTrial(){ 
        // The query here

        update liacc;
    }   

    public void SalesStageLostWinBack(){
        // The query here

        update liacc;
        system.debug(liacc.size());
        system.debug(liacc);
    }

    public void SalesStageColdMakeHot(){
        // The query here

        update liacc;
        system.debug(liacc.size());
        system.debug(liacc);
    }
}
```

All the methods have the same structure where each method does the 
SOQL -> add the result to the list -> iterate them in for loop and add to another list -> execute a DML statement at the end of the line, this is causing problem where the process hits the APEX CPU time limit for some methods that returned lots of result in the query.

The batch apex may solve the problem but it only limits the query flexibility in the start method if I'm not mistaken and I never tried queueable apex before.

I need an advice if I can use queueable apex or any other ways to solve my problem?

Comment: If the methods are independent, you could just split the tasks over several scheduled jobs and run them separately.

Comment: I thought the same but, however, if the query from one method returned thousand of records then the individual scheduled job would also hit the APEX CPU limit, no?

Comment: If you split it into separate jobs, they could in turn each hit the limit, that's true. If that is the case, you'd have to look into using Batch Apex (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_batch_interface.htm) to solve the problem (again, probably splitting it into separate batches would be advisable).

Comment: There's also the option to make the methods you currently have just be future methods if they're not reliant on any processing occurring first. If you know there's a lot of records each time (> 1000), then batchable does make more sense here.

Comment: in batchable, you can pass the query and the desired "method" to the constructor, thus allowing the schedulable to tell the batchable what to do

Comment: Thank you for all the comments, batch apex seems more reliable in my case, so I can separate the specific methods and scheduled them separately